# 3x images within divs, side by side, responsive

Tags: html, css, image, position

I've been picking my brain over this one for the past couple of days and think I'm going round in circles.

I'm trying to align 3 images side by side, to stretch across the browser window, no spaces inbetween.

I managed to do it having them contained within 1 div, using 'width: 33.3%' in the css, however, I need to have individual text appear on hover for each image, and it looks as though the only way this is possible is to have each image in its own div.

Now that each image is within its own div I've run into difficulty, and can't seem to crack this...

If someone could take a look at my code, and point me in the right direction it'd be a massive help - https://jsfiddle.net/j15288xj/

```
#slide2{
width: 100%;
}

.imgContainer{
float:left;
width: 33.3%;
}

#selector1{
}



#selector1:hover { 
-webkit-filter: brightness(25%);
}
```

As stated I can do this using width: 33.3% in the css for selector1,selector1,selector1 but it I need to do this for each div so I can display individual text to each element upon hovering over with the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL, take a look at your current image http://juiceyclub.webstarts.com/uploads/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square_svg.png your image has white space around it!

I used different images and changed your `css` slightly. Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/j15288xj/1/

```
img{width: 100%;}
#slide2{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.imgContainer{
    float:left;
    width: 33.3%;
}

#selector1{
}



#selector1:hover { 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(25%);
} 
#selector2{
}



#selector2:hover { 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(25%);
} 
#selector3{
}



#selector3:hover { 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(25%);
}
```

Comment: ha I actually noticed that myself, was working on this locally and just grabbed a square image for the fiddle.

Comment: thanks for sorting that out for me, I'm gonna take some more time to read about positioning + structuring